# access.log in MAMP works, error.log does not

Tags: php, logging, mamp

I created a new virtualhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.loc/"
    ServerName test.loc
    ServerAlias test.loc
    ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.loc/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.loc/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I created the `/logs/` folder, and voluntarily raised a php error.
My `access.log` appears and reports it correctly:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2020:12:04:11 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

`error.log` appears but is empty.

This is what I have in `php.ini`):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
```

As an alternative I tried to specify the log paths as relative (expecting them to appear relatively the project folder), no error is raised by MAMP at startup but the files don't appear anywhere.

Add-on: if I change `display_error`, both into `php.ini` or directly in my sample file, I get a meaningful feedback about the error. E.g.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.loc/error.php on line 3
```

I want that same thing, but logged.

Comment: What is your apache logLevel ? (httpd.conf)

Comment: `LogLevel error`

Comment: Setting it to `debug` actually makes stuff written in `error.log`, but anything related to the php error (I called a non-existant function)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding these to the virtualhost configuration:

```
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_log /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.loc/logs/error.log
```

I guess if there's a cleaner way to do this than setting it on each virtualhost? (is the standard `ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.loc/logs/error.log"` instruction not sufficient?)